# Update a record via a GraphQL API using Graphene and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, graphql, graphene-python

I am building a GraphQL API using the python packages Flask, SQLAlchemy, Graphene and Graphene-SQLAlchemy. I have followed the [SQLAlchemy + Flask Tutorial](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/sqlalchemy/en/latest/tutorial). I am able to execute queries and mutations to create records. Now I would like to know what is the best way to update an existing record.

Here is my current script **schema.py**:

```
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyObjectType
from database.batch import BatchOwner as BatchOwnerModel
import api_utils  # Custom methods to create records in database
import graphene


class BatchOwner(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    """Batch owners."""
    class Meta:
        model = BatchOwnerModel
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)


class CreateBatchOwner(graphene.Mutation):
    """Create batch owner."""
    class Arguments:
        name = graphene.String()

    # Class attributes
    ok = graphene.Boolean()
    batch_owner = graphene.Field(lambda: BatchOwner)

    def mutate(self, info, name):
        record = {'name': name}
        api_utils.create('BatchOwner', record) # Custom methods to create records in database
        batch_owner = BatchOwner(name=name)
        ok = True
        return CreateBatchOwner(batch_owner=batch_owner, ok=ok)


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    """Query endpoint for GraphQL API."""
    node = graphene.relay.Node.Field()
    batch_owner = graphene.relay.Node.Field(BatchOwner)
    batch_owners = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(BatchOwner)


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    """Mutation endpoint for GraphQL API."""
    create_batch_owner = CreateBatchOwner.Field()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

Remarks:

- My object `BatchOwner` has only 2 attributes (Id, name)
- To be able to update the `BatchOwner` name, I assume I need to provide the database Id (not the relay global Id) as an input argument of some update method
- But when I query for a `BatchOwner` from my client, Graphene only returns me the global Id which is base64 encoded (example: `QmF0Y2hPd25lcjox`, which correspond to `BatchOwner:1`)

Example of response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "batchOwners": {
            "edges": [
                {
                    "node": {
                        "id": "QmF0Y2hPd25lcjox",
                        "name": "Alexis"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The solution I am thinking of at the moment would be:

- Create an update mutation which takes the global Id as an argument
- Decode the global Id (how?)
- Use the database Id retrieved from the decoded global Id to query on the database and update the corresponding record

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a solution using the method `from_global_id` ([documented here](http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/relay/nodes/))

```
from graphql_relay.node.node import from_global_id
```

I added the following class to **schema.py**:

```
class UpdateBatchOwner(graphene.Mutation):
    """Update batch owner."""
    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.String()
        name = graphene.String()

    # Class attributes
    ok = graphene.Boolean()
    batch_owner = graphene.Field(lambda: BatchOwner)

    def mutate(self, info, id, name):
        id = from_global_id(id)
        record = {'id': id[1], 'name': name}
        api_utils.update('BatchOwner', record)
        batch_owner = BatchOwner(id=id, name=name)
        ok = True
        return UpdateBatchOwner(batch_owner=batch_owner, ok=ok)
```

And I updated the Mutation class:

```
class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    """Mutation endpoint for GraphQL API."""
    create_batch_owner = CreateBatchOwner.Field()
    update_batch_owner = UpdateBatchOwner.Field()
```

I'm wondering if there is a more straight forward way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you create a new instance of your model `BatchOwner`, then return it and this will automatically update the existing row (because it had the correct primary key `id`)? Can you elaborate on your solution and what it does, why it works please?

Comment: The class UpdateBatchOwner takes two arguments global id and name. In its mutate method, I convert the global id to database id with the method from_global_id, then I use a custom method api_utils.update which uses the class name, db id and name to update the name of the corresponding record. I think I would do things a bit differently now, check this example / tutorial: https://github.com/alexisrolland/flask-graphene-sqlalchemy/wiki also if you don’t mind changing tech stack I highly recommend this https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/ it’s much easier than SQLAlchemy